# Kotlin Plugin Not Found

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, plugins, mapbox

I have cloned the android mapbox maps from Github.  Found here:

> https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/

Straight out of the box I get the following error which I have been unable to solve:

> Build file
> 'C:\Development\mapbox-maps-android\mapbox-lint\build.gradle' line: 3
>
> Plugin [id: 'kotlin'] was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'kotlin'] was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (not a core plugin, please see https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/standard_plugins.html for
>   available core plugins)
> - Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

All files are identical to those currently on the Github repository.

Build.Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'kotlin'
    id 'com.android.lint'
}

lintOptions {
    htmlReport true
    htmlOutput file("lint-report.html")
    textReport true
    absolutePaths false
    ignoreTestSources true
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(Dependencies.lintApi)
    compileOnly(Dependencies.lintChecks)
    compileOnly(Dependencies.kotlin)
    testImplementation(Dependencies.junit)
    testImplementation(Dependencies.lint)
    testImplementation(Dependencies.lintTests)
    testImplementation(Dependencies.testUtils)
}
project.apply {
    from("$rootDir/gradle/ktlint.gradle")
}
```

Comment: There's no plain 'kotlin' Gradle plugin. Did you want the Kotlin Android plugin? Then you'll have to specify the full plugin ID and a version, `id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.5.31"` ([see here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android/1.5.31)).

Comment: Can you show the `Project level build.gradle file`.

Comment: @aSemy, thanks that worked can you post as an answer?   I now get a similar error for `id 'com.android.lint'` do you have a link for that I cant seem to find the correct reference.

Comment: @Reafidy I am also getting the same error, how did you solve it?

Comment: @Reafidy yes me too. Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer by aSemy.

There's no plain 'kotlin' Gradle plugin. Did you want the Kotlin Android plugin? Then you'll have to specify the full plugin ID and a version,

```
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.5.31"
```